# How do I create an array of hashes in Perl with 8 headers/columns and 20 rows using for loop

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I'm a beginner in Perl and learning to use arrays and hashes. With the research I did, I created an array> with keys and values for one of the hash columns. I'm not sure how to horizontally put the headers and make rows under each of the 8 headers. Any help is very appreciated again.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# use strict;
use warnings;
# use 5.010;
use Data::Dumper;

my %Name = (
    Component => 2.2
);

foreach my $name (keys %Name) {
    printf "%-8s %s\n", $name, $Name{$name};
}
```

But this is what I'm trying to print in the console: headers(8) and last      header is empty.

```
 Type            Name                               Rev Id      ZZZ ID  IP     Group        Date Released  AA Category  Project IDs
 xxxxxComponent xyz_abc_1234LDO_c7rp1avrusevrmdtop  xxxx_2_5    99ccccc1      ABC- RIP-xxxxx    2015-05-03 6:59:09  xxxx    
 xxxxxComponent xyz_abc_1234LDO_c7rp1avrusevrmdtop  xxxx_2_5    99ccccc1    ABC  RIP xxxxx  2015-05-03 6:59:09  xxxx
 xxxxxComponent xyz_abc_1234LDO_c7rp1avrusevrmdtop  xxxx_2_5    99ccccc1    ABC RIP xxxxx   2015-05-03 6:59:09  xxxx
```

Comment: Re "I created an array> with keys and values for one of the hash columns." You created a hash with one element. That's it. How do you expect to print data you don't actually have? Fix that first.

Comment: Your program defines a _hash_ with a single key called `Component`. However, you now print an entire row of this `%Name` hash and not one of the keys equals `2.2`. Where did all of the data come from? Is `%Name` containing this data? How are you putting this data in `%Name`? We can't help you out without a  better understanding what your data looks like, and your program.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to build an array of records, where each item in the array is a hash reference.  Then you can loop through those to print them out.

Here's a quick example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @records =
( { "Type" => "Type A",
    "Name" => "Name A",
    "Group" => 1 },

  { "Type" => "Type B",
    "Name" => "Name B",
    "Group" => 2 },

 { "Type" => "Type C",
   "Name" => "Name C",
   "Group" => 2 },
  );

printf "%-8s %-8s %-2s\n",
    "Type",
    "Name",
    "Group";

for my $record (@records) {
    printf "%-8s %-8s %-2s\n",
    $record->{Type},
    $record->{Name},
    $record->{Group}
}
```

Which prints:

```
Type     Name     Group
Type A   Name A   1
Type B   Name B   2
Type C   Name C   2
```

Comment: #thank you Kevin, your format was very helpful for me to understand arrays, key, value, hashes and for loop. I would like to show what my output was in the console using this code:

Comment: I tried executing this code with 8 column names and 20 different rows. I have some issues with the alignment. I tried adjusting the "%-8s %-8s %-2s %-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s\n" is there a better way I could do it? such as use  a hash reference to read the formattd txt file and display the txt file in console in an aligned way OR use a module?

Comment: I am not very familiar with installing any Perl module. Is there anyway I could execute it in an online IDE to check the result?

Comment: I saw your [other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269505/how-to-align-table-headers-to-rows-in-perl) asking about tables.  The suggestion to use Text::Table::Tiny was a good one.  So I assume that's the module you're trying to avoid installing?

Can you explain what "issues" you are having with alignment?

Comment: Yes I was not successful installing the Perl module. I downloaded Text::Table::Tiny from cpan and tried installing in cmd. I unpacked the tar.gz file and ran the Makefile.PL but it gives me a message saying that the lib, bin, t folders are empty inform the author. So after many unsuccessful iterations I decided to use the method above. But my first, three columns look aligned but from fourth to eighth doesn't look aligned. I figured it out it is because of these numbers %-8s %-8s %-2s. How do I decide on these numbers when writing the program for fourth to eighth column?

Comment: Do you know the maximum width for each field in advance? If so, then just use that in the format string. (for example, if 1st field max with is 8, then use %-8s for the first entry in the format string.) if you don't know it in advance, then you need to compute it yourself from the data. (Like Text::Table::Tiny does.)

Comment: I figured it out that computing the size of each field is a laborious task. I also searched up that using a split function would be a less time consuming task. Can I plug in a split function in the code above to do that job?

Comment: This is the data table(read file). I read this file and trying to create an array of hashes in the 'while' loop to read each row and split each column using a delimiter tab. 
#Type   #Name   #Rev Id  #ZZZ ID  #IP Group        #Date Released    #AA Category #Project IDs
xxxxxComponent xyz_abc_1234LDO_c7rp1avrusevrmdtop xxxx_2_5 99ccccc1 ABC RIP xxxxx 2015-05-03 6:59:09 xxxx 
xxxxxComponent xyz_abc_1234LDO_c7rp1avrusevrmdtop xxxx_2_5 99ccccc1 ABC RIP xxxxx 2015-05-03 6:59:09 xxxx
xxxxxComponent xyz_abc_1234LDO_c7rp1avrusevrmdtop xxxx_2_5 99ccccc1 ABC RIP xxxxx 2015-05-03 6:59:09 xxxx 

...

Comment: You can use split() to divide each data row into its fields, sure. But that has nothing to do with the layout problem when you print.

Comment: Example:  Is the "Name" column always 34 characters or fewer?  (That's what I count in your original question, but don't know if that holds for all the data.)  If so, then use "%-34s" as the 2nd entry in your formatting string, to make the Name field 34 characters wide (and left-justified).